# Mono's mdb debugger?

Tags: debugging, mono

[This site](http://www.mono-project.com/Guide%3aDebugger) explains about the [Mono](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mono_%28software%29) debugger (mdb), but I can't run/find mdb on my Mac/Mono (Mono 2.8.1).

```
smcho@prosseek ver3> mdb
-bash: mdb: command not found
```

Doesn't Mono 2.8.1 ship with mdb?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not believe mdb is supported on Mac.  I know it's definitely not supported on Windows.

All current and future debugger development effort is on the soft debugger (sdb), which is much easier to support on various platforms.  However, it does not have a command line interface at this time.

http://www.mono-project.com/Soft_Debugger